# Help needed, re: removing accidentally created tag

Tags: support

As I was editing a post, I accidentally clicked "Save edits" while typing (tags). Can someone with the ability to delete tags kindly remove the one I accidentally created ("syn")?

Thank you so much. I don't know if this is an appropriate post here on Meta, but I don't know where to seek help about what happened.

UPDATE (for reference): I am referring to a 'created' tag. If it was created, I'm not certain; it shows up if I search for it under the tags search.

[image]

Comment: I think the solution should be quite simple. Re-edit the post, and delete the tag you created inadvertently. Let us know if it worked :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thank you for this! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) explains that tags with no associated questions are deleted at 03:00 UTC each day.

As Mari-Lou said in her comment, simply edit the post to remove the tag and it should go away within 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks, @ColleenV. I guess I just have to wait until it is automatically deleted. :)